# Можно ли сделать лэндинг на всю ширину экрана?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, веб-дизайн

Приветствую. Верстаю лэндинг по psd шаблону. Вся ширина макета - 1366px.

На картинке уже сверстанный шаблон.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается шаблон центрируется по середине. Не могу понять можно ли сделать такой лэндинг на всю ширину окна экрана или это не предусмотрено дизайнером, т.к. размеры все фиксированные в шаблоне???

Вот часть кода первых верхних блоков как на пикче:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  min-width: 320px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-family: 'RobotoRegular', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #262f32;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,h2,{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 1366px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.clearfix {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.header-block {
  height: 715px;
}

.header-block-left {
  width: 908px;
  height: 715px;
  float: left;
}

.header-block-right {
  width: 458px;
  height: 715px;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
}

.title-project {
  width: 347px;
  height: 563px;
  margin-top: 76px;
  margin-left: 54px;
}

.title-project h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 76px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.title-project h2 span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.title-project h2 span:nth-child(1) {
  font-family: 'RobotoLight', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #636869;
}

.title-project h2 span:nth-child(2) {
  font-family: 'RobotoBold', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #262f32;
}

.title-project h2 span:nth-child(3) {
  font-family: 'RobotoRegular', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #262F32;
}

.title-project > p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  color: #636869;
}

.title-project p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-block container">
    <div class="header-block-left">
     <img src="img/block-1.png" width="908" height="715" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="header-block-right">

     <header class="title-project">

        <div class="button-menu">
       <img src="img/buttn_mnu.png" width="33" height="29" alt="">
     </div>

      <h2>

       <span>Ali Sayed's</span>
       <span>Web Designing</span>
       <span>Project</span>

      </h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore.</p>
      <p>quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea ommodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dol.</p>
     </header>
      
     </div>
    </div>
```

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Конечно можно. Вопрос лишь в том, зачем вы верстали сайт, задавая блокам фиксированный размер.

Comment: `.container {
  width: 1366px;}` меняешь на .container `{
  width: 100%; }` - и получаешь на всю ширину!